# MongoDB and express, connection timeout when attempting an insertMany

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm starting to learn node, express, and mongodb.

In one of my getting started exercises I'm trying to do single and multiple inserts into a collection called `documents`.

Single inserts work fine:

```
let express = require('express')
let app = express()

let MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
let assert = require('assert')
let url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test'

app.get('/testInsert',(req,res) => {
    MongoClient.connect(url, (err, db) => {
        assert.equal(null, err)
        console.log("Connected to mongo server")

        let collection = db.collection('documents')

        // this works fine
        collection.insertOne({test: 'worked'}, (err, rec) => {
            assert.equal(null, err)
            assert.equal(1, rec.insertedCount)
            console.log('single insert result: ' + rec)
            db.close();
            res.send('single insert result: ' + rec)
        })

    })
})
```

But when I try to insert many I get a timeout:

```
let express = require('express')
let app = express()

let MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
let assert = require('assert')
let url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test'

app.get('/testInsert',(req,res) => {
    MongoClient.connect(url, (err, db) => {
        assert.equal(null, err)
        console.log("Connected to mongo server")

        let collection = db.collection('documents')

        // This fires
        console.log('about to start insert many')
        collection.insertMany([{greeting: 'hi'}, {greeting: 'hey'}, {greeting: 'yo'}]), (err, recs) => {
            // I never get past here
            console.log('finished insert many')
            assert.equal(err,null)
            assert.equal(3,recs.result.n)
            assert.equal(3,recs.insertedCount)
            db.close();
            res.send("multi insert result: " + recs)
        }
    })
})
```

When I try hitting the endpoint I get a request timeout:
[image: error message]

But when I check mongo the records are definitely inserted:
[image: records inserted]

I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong with the mongo insert because I never get to the first line of my callback. Is there something that I'm doing wrong when trying to insert multiple documents into mongo?

Comment: I think there is a syntax error in the line "collection.insertmany"; there shouldn't a closing ) after the closing ]. It closes the call to insertMany() and does not get to the call backs

Comment: Ah, good catch, that extra parens is what was causing the issue. Thanks!

Comment: I will add that as an answer so you can pick it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this line in your code:

```
"collection.insertMany([{greeting: 'hi'}, {greeting: 'hey'}, {greeting: 'yo'}]), (err, recs) "
```

There shouldn't be a closing parens ) after the closing  bracket ]. I think if you fix that it should help.